# MapReduce : Transform row-based data to a hierarchical form

Tags: xml, hadoop, design-patterns, mapreduce, hierarchical-data

Follwing problem and code is from MapReduce design pattern.

Problem: Given a list of posts and comments, create a structured XML hierarchy to nest comments with their related post.

Throwing NullPointer Exception.I cannot catch my mistake. I really appreciate any help I can get.

Here is my class and the nestElement method:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

//import javax.swing.text.html.parser.Element;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.MultipleInputs;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer.Context;
import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
//import org.w3c.dom.UserDataHandler;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
public class PostCommentHierarchy {
        public static class PostMapper extends Mapper<Object,Text,Text,Text>{
                private Text outkey = new Text();
                private Text outvalue = new Text();

                public void map(Object key,Text value,Context context)throws IOException ,InterruptedException{
                        Map<String,String> parsed = MRDPUtils.transformXmlToMap(value.toString());
                        String line = value.toString();
                        if(!(line.length()<=0)){
                        outkey.set(parsed.get("Id"));
                        outvalue.set("P"+value.toString());
                        context.write(outkey, outvalue);
                        }
                }
        }

        public static class CommentMapper extends Mapper<Object,Text,Text,Text>{
                private Text outkey = new Text();
                private Text outvalue = new Text();

                public void map(Object key, Text value,Context context)throws IOException,InterruptedException{
                        Map<String,String> parsed = MRDPUtils.transformXmlToMap(value.toString());
                        String line = value.toString();
                        if(!(line.length()<=0)){
                        outkey.set(parsed.get("PostId"));

                        outvalue.set("C"+value.toString());
                        context.write(outkey, outvalue);
                        }
                }
        }
        public static class PostCommentHierarchyReducer extends Reducer <Text,Text,Text,NullWritable>{
                private ArrayList<String> comments = new ArrayList<String>();
                private DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                private String post = null;

                public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<Text>values,Context context)throws IOException,InterruptedException{
                        post =null;
                        comments.clear();

                        for(Text t:values){
                            if(t.charAt(0)== 0){
                                return;
                            }else if(t.charAt(0)=='P'){
                                        post = t.toString().substring(1,t.toString().length()).trim();
                                }else{
                                        comments.add(t.toString().substring(1,t.toString().length()).trim());
                                }
                        }

                        if(post != null){
                                String postWithCommentChildren = null;
                                try {
                                        try {
                                                postWithCommentChildren = nestElements(post,comments);
                                        } catch (TransformerException e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (SAXException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                context.write(new Text(postWithCommentChildren), NullWritable.get());
                        }
                }

                private String nestElements(String post,List<String> comments) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, TransformerException{
                        DocumentBuilder bldr = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                        Document doc = bldr.newDocument();

                        org.w3c.dom.Element postEl = getXmlElementFromString(post);
                        org.w3c.dom.Element toAddPostEl = doc.createElement("post");
//                      Element toAddPostEl1 = doc.createElement("post");

                        copyAttributesToElement(postEl.getAttributes(),toAddPostEl);

                        for(String commentXml:comments){
                                org.w3c.dom.Element commentEl = getXmlElementFromString(commentXml);
                                org.w3c.dom.Element toAddCommentEl = doc.createElement("comments");

                                copyAttributesToElement(commentEl.getAttributes(),toAddCommentEl);
                                toAddPostEl.appendChild(toAddPostEl);
                        }
                        doc.appendChild(toAddPostEl);
                    // Transform the document into a String of XML and return
                        return transformDocumentToString(doc);
                }
                private org.w3c.dom.Element getXmlElementFromString(String xml) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
                        DocumentBuilder bldr = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                        return bldr.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)))
                                        .getDocumentElement();

                }

                private void copyAttributesToElement(NamedNodeMap attributes,org.w3c.dom.Element toAddPostEl){
                        for(int i = 0; i<attributes.getLength();++i){
                                Attr toCopy = (Attr) attributes.item(i);
                                toAddPostEl.setAttribute(toCopy.getName(),toCopy.getValue());

                        }
                }

                private String transformDocumentToString(Document doc) throws TransformerException{

                        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
                        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");

                        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                        //Acts as a holder for a transformation Source tree in the form of a Document Object Model (DOM) tree.
                        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
                        return writer.getBuffer().toString().replaceAll("\n|\r", "");
                }

        }
        public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException{

                //check how multiple inputs job works?

                Configuration conf = new Configuration();
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                Job job = new Job(conf,"PostCommentHierarchy");
                job.setJarByClass(PostCommentHierarchy.class);
                job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
                job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

                MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]),TextInputFormat.class,PostMapper.class);
                MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]),TextInputFormat.class ,CommentMapper.class);

                job.setReducerClass(PostCommentHierarchyReducer.class);
                job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
                TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));


                System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)? 0 :1);
        }

}
```

Comment: please add the exception trace that you are getting..

Comment: 15/09/14 15:44:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1439888371132_0313_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.encode(Text.java:443)
 at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.set(Text.java:198)
 at PostCommentHierarchy$CommentMapper.map(PostCommentHierarchy.java:61)
 at PostCommentHierarchy$CommentMapper.map(PostCommentHierarchy.java:1)

Comment: There is no try catch or comments, in map method. May be your exception, occurs at places other than those. You can test your Job, like a typical java program using small input and verify logs. Anything stopping you from doing that? Or is it that, your mapper is not at all picked up? Then, you need to verify how your input formats are configured in job and whats the actual input

Comment: wonderful comments. Thanks  a lot Ramzy. try and catch helps me  in mapping side.